# Extracting data from volatile memory

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, bytecode, dalvik

I have an encrypted dex file which is being decrypted in a buffer. As far as i understand if a user roots the device the decrypted bytecode can be extracted from volatile memory.

Now is it possible to protect extraction of bytecode from memory or what is the best that can be done to protect that bytecode?

I know android is java based and open source yet i am looking for a solutions that can raise the bar for reverse engineering.

Regards,

Shoaib

Answer (score 1):

At some point the unencrypted code has to exist in memory, or the processor can't run it.  I think you're past the point of diminishing returns already.

Comment: well this is the fact and i understand :) i just wanted to discuss if there were a better approach may be.

Comment: A better approach would be using a license.